# What was the reason for Deadpool always forgetting these items?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

In the Deadpool movie, Deadpool forgets his ammo bag in the first scene in the taxi and then forgets his guns bag in the second scene with the same taxi. This seems too convenient to just to make for some funny scenes.

And the first ends with doing a scene with just 12 bullets in his gun.

Then the fight with after he forgets his gun bag,

Comment: *Deadpool* isn't part of the MCU.

Comment: @RogueJedi, which is why I was hesitant in adding the tag. But, seeming as though X-men is, maybe the tag is warranted? If not ,I will edit the post.

Comment: the x-men are also not part of the MCU.

Comment: @phantom42, edited. Sorry, these tags are not my cup of tea.

Comment: “This seems too convenient to just to make for some funny scenes.” You’re confused at a comedy film having a joke in it?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite. It was funny the first time, but the second got me thinking. Ultimately it was due to budget cuts, but still it was funny, so don't confuse curiosity with satisfaction, I really enjoyed the scenes..

Comment: One of the key components to comedy is repetition.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with X-Men comics, but from the movie I got the idea that Deadpool is a little absent-minded and unfocused. Such people forget their stuff all the time.

Comment: The second key component to comedy is repetition. @phantom42

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr The third key component to comedy is [The Rule of Three](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfThree)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**The issue of the forgotten ammunition pack in the first Taxi ride and the forgotten guns bag was due to budget cuts from Fox.**

---

Fox forced the crew to cut $7 million from the script at the last minute from an already limited budget of a $58 million. In an interview with MTV Ryan Reynolds talks about the very low budget, [“The budget isn’t what we hoped it would be, this [flanel shirt] is actually the suit,”](http://www.mtv.com/news/2059223/ryan-reynolds-deadpool/)

And [Reynolds](https://weminoredinfilm.com/2016/02/16/how-the-limitations-of-a-small-budget-forced-the-deadpool-team-to-make-a-much-better-movie/) did have a hard time developing the movie due to the studios constraints, Reynolds said,

> We went through such hell developing the script and which X-Men we
>   could keep and which we couldn’t and it just turned into a nightmare.
>   The studio would just say, ‘too expensive, too expensive, too
>   expensive’ to everyone. So finally we were like well, “What about
>   Negasonic Teenage Warhead” and they said, “Negasonic, what?”

And screenwriter [Rhett Reese](http://io9.gizmodo.com/everything-that-was-too-expensive-to-include-in-deadpoo-1759651069?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20io9%2Ffull%20%28io9%29) said ,

> There was a reduction of action. We had a motorcycle chase between
>   Deadpool and Ajax (Francis) on the freeway that we took out. We had a
>   big, big gun fight in the third act that we took out and **we basically**
>   **had Deadpool forget his guns as a means of getting around it.** So there
>   were just reductions.

There is more on this on ["How the Limitations of a Small Budget Forced the Deadpool Team to Make a Much Better Movie"](https://weminoredinfilm.com/2016/02/16/how-the-limitations-of-a-small-budget-forced-the-deadpool-team-to-make-a-much-better-movie/)

Comment: Well, at least Fox can still enjoy their mountain of cash that the movie made despite them cheaping out on stuff.

Comment: "an already limited budget of a $58 million" ... some people are just not good with money.

Comment: @Peter. Compared to other super hero movies, this is not much. Cheap for this day and age. http://www.hollywood.com/movies/marvel-superhero-movie-budgets-60223164/#/ms-22196/17