# Was there ever consideration of a scene concerning Beast in Deadpool?

Tags: x-men, marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

Near the end of the 2016 film Deadpool, one of the lines Wade shouts out is:

> "And tell Beast to stop shitting on my lawn!"

I heard rumors that they had actually considered bringing in Nicholas Hoult as Beast, but I didn't know if this was true.

**Was Nicholas Hoult ever considered to appear in *Deadpool*?**

Comment: Same answer as here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129502/what-was-the-reason-for-deadpool-always-forgetting-these-items

Comment: I've removed the second part of your question because asking multiple-questions-in-one is discouraged. You're welcome to ask it separately

Comment: Oh, I know. I just added the second part to empathize the fact that Deadpool is stating a low budget on his film by commenting on the 'studio couldn't afford another X-Man?'

Comment: It would be a very good idea to register your account (create a login for it); otherwise you could find it disappears during your browsers next cookie clear-up!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparently this was actually a serious consideration<sup>1</sup>; [Film School Rejects reports on](https://filmschoolrejects.com/47-things-we-learned-from-the-deadpool-commentary-db6eed0a1160#.a5qada283) the *Deadpool* commentary track (on the DVD release), and note:

> They originally wanted the end credits scene to feature Beast shitting on Wilson’s lawn and then running off as Wilson shakes his morning newspaper, but they had to settle for a joke about it instead. “Nicholas Hoult was game,” says Reynolds, but they couldn’t make their schedules work.

---

<sup>1</sup> As serious as anything involving this movie was, anyway

Comment: Simply brilliant.

Comment: @Jason Baker-Aw, too bad; that would have been a funny scene. Oh, well, maybe they could find a way to slip it into Deadpool 2. Thanks!

Comment: Begging for accepts? :)